# Array of Hashes to Hash Conversion while preventing Key Override

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

How would you convert:

```
x = [
 {"a" => ["a","b","c","d","e"]}, 
 {"f" => ["f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]}, 
 {"f" => ["o","p"]}
]
```

Into:

```
{
 "a"=>["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], 
 "f" => ["f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]}, 
 "f01"=>["o", "p"] 
}
```

I originally was using

```
x.reduce({},:update)
```

however this overrides the first "f" (because keys are unique).

I have scoured for answers but have not found anything that would work in this case.

Comment: Are there any requirements for the renaming scheme? If there aren't, it's pretty trivial.

Comment: What should happen if the input is `[{"a"=>[1], "b"=>[2]}, {"a"=>[3], "a01"=>[4]}]`?

Comment: You're trying to consolidate an array of hashes into a single hash, while maintaining the uniqueness in case of any key-collisions, but the resulting hash is going to be very difficult to search or manipulate. It would help a lot if you'd explain your use-case. As is it looks like you're walking into a world of hurt down the road.

Comment: Your expected output is not valid Ruby.

Comment: What is the rule for `"f01"`? Is the number always padded with one `"0'`, or is it padded to be two digits, or, ...?

Comment: The naming scheme would just need to have some sort of numerical increment it could be f1 or f01

Comment: @theTinMan it would be a very long explanation, in the end I need to prevent the collision while preserving the format listed above. In the end I could care less what the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resulting hash, after changing keys, is going to result in a very difficult problem: How are you going to easily look up the resulting hashes and their arrays?

I'd recommend rethinking the sort of hash you want. Instead of creating new hash keys that will be difficult to look up and have a tenuous association with the original hash key, reuse the original keys and create hash keys that point to arrays of arrays. Starting with a much simpler starting array of hashes:

```
x = [
  {'a' => ['a', 'b']},
  {'f' => ['f', 'g']},
  {'f' => ['o', 'p']}
]
```

Here's the code:

```
hash = x.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = [] }) { |e, h| 
  k, v = e.flatten
  h[k] << v
}

pp hash
```

This is the output:

```
{"a"=>[["a", "b"]], "f"=>[["f", "g"], ["o", "p"]]}
```

Lookups become more simple:

```
hash['f'][0]
# => ["f", "g"]
hash['f'].last
# => ["o", "p"]
```

You maintain the separation of the original arrays, while gaining a more logical and much simpler lookup.

If you need to know how many sub-arrays are assigned to a hash it's easy too:

```
hash['f'].size
# => 2
```

If you want to iterate over all the `'f'` entries, which is what would become convoluted and difficult with your design, simply do:

```
hash['f'].each do |f|
  ...
end
```

or:

```
hash['f'].map { |f|
  ...
}
```

Comment: After testing all of the suggestions here, this was the most feasable. Thank you so much for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `01` part of `f01` is just a counter and you don't care about formatting that number you could do the following:

```ruby
def reduce_update_incr(arr)
  key_count = {}
  arr.reduce({}) do |memo,h|
    h.each do |k,v|
      k = k + (key_count[k]=(key_count[k]||0)+1).to_s if memo.include?(k)
      memo[k] = v
    end
    memo
  end
end

reduce_update_incr(x)
# {"a"=>["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
#  "f"=>["f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"],
#  "f1"=>["o", "p"]}
```

Yuck.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `inject` as follows:

```
 > x.inject({}){|r,h| r[h.keys.first] ||= [] ; r[h.keys.first] << h.values.first; r}
  => {"a"=>[["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]], 
      "f"=>[["f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"], ["o", "p"]]}
```

Please note that you will get multiple arrays for the same key. (I.E. `"f"`)

The resulting hash is slightly different from what you asked for, but it might be even easier to use, because there is no confusion with modified keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [
 {"a" => ["a","b","c","d","e"]}, 
 {"f" => ["f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"]}, 
 {"f" => ["o","p"]}
]

res = x.collect{|d| d.first}.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), h, n = "00"|
  (k += n.next!) if (h.key? k)
  h[k] = v
end

res == {
 "a"=>["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], 
 "f" => ["f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"], 
 "f01"=>["o", "p"] 
}
```

Comment: `until (h[k].nil?)` can be written `if h.key?(k)`. `until (h[k].nil?)` is basically `if !(h[k].nil?)` vs. `if h.key?(k)`.